# Odoo 12: Add a custom sidebar to the Form View

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I've recently started working with Odoo, and decided to try my hand at customising the form view. Basically, what I want to do is add a custom sidebar to the default form view of, say, the new receipts of the Inventory app. It'd look something like this:

[image: Custom Sidebar Mockup]

Here's what I tried: I created a module in which I wrote a widget as well as its template:

### sidebar.js

```
odoo.define('sidebar_widget.bh_sidebar', function (require) {
  'use strict';

  var Widget = require('web.Widget');
  var widgetRegistry = require('web.widget_registry');
  var core = require('web.core');

  var QWeb = core.qweb;
  var _t = core._t;

  var bh_sidebar = Widget.extend({
    init: function () {
        var self = this;
        this._super(parent);
        console.log('Widget initialized!');
    },

    events: {},

    start: function () {
        this.$el.append(QWeb.render('bh_sidebar_template'));
    }

  });

  widgetRegistry.add(
    'bh_sidebar', bh_sidebar
  )
})
```

Pretty basic. Here's what the template looks like:

### sidebar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
   <t t-name="bh_sidebar_template">
       <div style="background-color:red;" class="myClass">
           <a href="#" class="butt1">Button 1</a>
           <a href="#" class="butt2">Button 2</a>
       </div>
   </t>
</templates>
```

I wasn't sure where to go after writing the js and xml files, so I simply added the widget to the inventory form view as follows:

### view.xml

```
<odoo>
   <data>
    <record id="bh_sidebar_id" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sidebar_widget.bh_sidebar</field>
        <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//header" position="after">
                <widget name="bh_sidebar" />
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
   </data>
</odoo>
```

Problem is, The widget displays the QWeb template inside of the form, but I want it outside of it, above the cancel button and the document status widget. [image: Imgur]
See the red bar there, I want that outside of the  element, but I can't do that since the  was added inside of the inherited form view.

I'd like to know if it's possible to invoke the widget outside of the form. Maybe what I'm doing is wrong, and there is another, simpler solution out there. I'd really appreciate any feedback!